# Powershell SqlCommand and StreamWriter slow write

Tags: performance, powershell, file-io, streamwriter, sqlcommand

I'm writing a PowerShell script that pulls arbitrary SQL queries from a database.  Those queries can become extremely large, and after trying sqlcmd I ended up with a StreamWriter / SqlCommand combination.  The problem I'm having is that execution is a little slow.  Like 10x as slow.  I've been told it should be faster, hence the question.
To Code!

```
                $conn.ChangeDatabase("MyDB")
                $mycmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Myquery, $conn) 
                $mycmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
                $mycmd.CommandTimeout = 300
                echo "Executing Reader."        
                $Results = $mycmd.ExecuteReader()


                echo "Opening file for writing."                    
                $sw2 = new-object system.IO.StreamWriter($sqlOutput, 1)
                echo "File Opened for Writing."     
                $delimiter = ","
                echo "Starting Row Reading"
                $Counter = $Results.FieldCount
                echo $Counter
                # Put in header row on first execution.
                $currtext = ""
                if ($Counter -gt 0)
                {
                    echo "Writing Header Row as:"
                    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Counter; $i++)
                    {
                        $currtext = $currtext + $Results.GetName($i)
                        if ($i -lt $Counter - 1)
                        {$currtext = $currtext + $delimiter}
                    }

                    echo $currtext
                    $sw2.writeline($currtext)
                    $firstexecution = 0
                }
                else
                {
                    $sw2.writeline("No Data Found")
                }

                $rowcount = 0
                while ($Results.Read())
                {
                    $rowcount = $rowcount + 1
                    #echo "Reading Row"
                    $i = 0
                    $currtext = ""
                    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Counter; $i++)
                    {
                        #echo "Processing Row"
                        $currtext = $currtext + """" + [string]$Results[$i] + """" 
                        if ($i -lt $Counter - 1)
                            { $currtext = $currtext + $delimiter }
                    }
                    #echo "Writing Line."
                    #echo $currtext
                    $sw2.writeline($currtext)
                }
                echo "Total Rowcount:" + $rowcount
                $sw2.flush()
                $sw2.close()
                $sw2.dispose()
                $Results.close()
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong / how to fix it?

Comment: It would help alot if you actually said when it became slow. You got a lot of echos during your script, so what's the last message before it gets really slow? Also, sqlcmd will probably be faster(I haven't tested it), because with powershell you need to generate objects etc. while sqlcmd can just write down unparsed lines.

Comment: The chunk that is going to be important, from a performance perspective, is the part that reads row-by-row, meaning the while loop.  The while loop can currently read / write around five megs of data a minute, which seems slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Snapins:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

Call your variables:

```
$SQLUsername        = "user"
$SQLPassword        = "password"
$SQLDatabase        = "database"
$SQLServer          = "localhost"
```

Grab your data:

```
$DBComputers = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword `
 -Database $SQLDatabase -Query "SELECT * FROM Physical WHERE Retired=0 AND OS LIKE '%Windows%' ORDER BY Name"
```

Iteriate through the rows:

```
foreach ( $DBComputer in $DBComputers ) {

    Write-Host $DBComputer.Name    ##$DBComputer.COLUMNNAME

}
```

I've done alot of SQL with PowerShell by using the following example above. The example above queries data on a SQL Standard instance on a Dell R720 server with pretty darn good speed. Is this a Microsoft Access Database or a true SQL instance? The Access Engine is not ideal plus a lot would matter based on your disk type.

You mentioned a large dataset, I think the biggest thing is to make sure the database is indexed and running a real SQL engine without knowing more about the database from a non-code perspective.

Comment: This is a true SQL instance, and since the queries are arbitrary the structure doesn't matter much.  It's data throughput that's the problem.  And the problem is fairly large; the data is around 100MB in the instance I've recently run into.  I was using SQLCMD before, but misdiagnosed a memory / size issue (my buffer for writing to a ZIP file was running out of memory at 100MB) and rewrote it to use a StreamWriter.  I'm curious why my performance difference is so large.

Comment: You could be doing unnecessary loops? Not completely sure but working on the example provided you can simply do the following to get it into CSV format all in a one-liner since that is what you're doing pretty much, just manually. 

`Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM Physical" | Export-Csv -Path C:\Export.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Does Export-Csv manage field quoting well?  Invoke-Sqlcmd has options for picking delimitation and exporting, but the output didn't come out as clean as it needed to to be useful.  As a side note, my previous implementation was:      sqlcmd -Q $Myquery -d $CurrentDB -S $CurrentServer -o $sqlOutput -E -k -W -s " " -t 500

Comment: Export-Csv has parameters to define a delimiter with `-Delimiter ","` [Export-CSV Link](http://ss64.com/ps/export-csv.html). It's certainly with experimentation but I don't see why it wouldn't carry over quotes if needed. There is a parameter for quoting `-I enable Quoted Identifiers` see [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Quoted identifiers doesn't necessarily mean the data will be quoted.  I tried replacing -s " (tab char here) " with -s """,""" and it gave me the output I wanted.